# 403(Forbidden), Invalid Key Error On Google Speech API

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-403, google-speech-api

I am trying to access speech api using following url and always getting 403(Forbidden) Error, Invalid Key.

https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key={MyKey}

I have tried with both Server Key and Browser key as shown on this [Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OGpf.png) image.

I am sending http request using .NET HTTP Client; Code snippet is given below:

```
Stream stream = null;
            StreamReader sr = null;
            WebResponse response = null;
            JSon.RecognizedItem result;
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Constants.GoogleRequestString);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=" + sampleRate;
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                stream = request.GetRequestStream();

                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                stream.Close();

                response = request.GetResponse();

                stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Can't get a response from server. Response stream is null.");
                }
                sr = new StreamReader(stream);

                //Get response in JSON format
                string respFromServer = sr.ReadToEnd();

                var parsedResult = JSon.Parse(respFromServer);
                result =
                    parsedResult.hypotheses.Where(d => d.confidence == parsedResult.hypotheses.Max(p => p.confidence)).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.Close();

                if (sr != null)
                    sr.Close();

                if (response != null)
                    response.Close();
            }

            return result == null ? "" : result.utterance;
```

Can anybody please help me to identify the problem here.

Thanks,
Ab.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: You can try with this url: https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?client=chromium&lang=en_US&key=[YOUR_KEY_HERE]

Comment: What does the yellow warning icon indicate when hovered? If sending the request from a browser, you can only use a browser key. Finally, your code doesn't seem to use the key itself.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For that [API endpoint](https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=%7BMyKey%7D), usage quota is no longer offered. And, apparently, it was an endpoint specific for community developers for [the Chromium project](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys).

Google's Speech API is [the Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) .

The [keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OGpf.png) you are referencing appear to be set up in your Google Cloud Project (GCP). GCP, implicitly those keys, can be linked to the [Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started), as pointed out [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/), not the https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/ one.